# µ-law Amplification

Tags: c#, audio

Can anyone explain the algorithm for amplifying G.711 µ-law encoded audio?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm

Comment: Yes, I was able to find that. Unfortunately I wasn't quite able to comprehend how to amplify the audio from that. Can you give me a hint or a more detailed explanation of how µ-law works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each byte, subtract a value such as 0x10. This moves the amplitude to the next range in the sequence. Also increases the amplitude range, but the effect seemed negligible for my files.